# How to identify columns which are best candidate for Indexing

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have read a lot of thread on identifying columns which can be the best candidate for creating indexes. However, most of them advise creating indexes on columns which are used in JOIN or WHERE clause.

Still, I am not sure for complex queries like below

```
select b.col1 ,a.col1 ,a.selectionId ,a.table2Id ,a.selectionName ,b.UserId,b.ParantId ,
a.teamType ,d.Name,b.isBack,b.SelectionId,b.Admin AS admin,
b.Master AS master,c.MstDate AS MstDate, c.col2 
from  tblselection a 
       join  table1 c on c.col1 = a.col1 
       join  table2 d on d.Id = a.table2Id 
        left join  tabletest b on b.SelectionId = a.selectionId and a.table2Id = b.table2Id and b.IsMatched = 1
       where ((ifnull(c.active,0) = 1) and isnull(b.Result) and isnull(b.ResultID))
```

Which columns are the best candidate for indexing in all 4 tables for this query?

I Should create composite indexes or individual indexes here?

Comment: I assume that this is MySQL, not SQL Server? `ifnull` isn't a T-SQL function.

Comment: @Larnu : yes its MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Run your query with the `EXPLAIN` keyword in front of it (`EXPLAIN SELECT b.cl1, a.col1 ...`). MySQL will give you a breakdown of how things are joined together and how many rows it scans to figure it out.

Typically you want indexes on the columns that get referenced, especially if it needs to look at a lot of rows or if it's using "Table-scan" to join them. You want it to say "using primary" or "using index"

Here's some example output from one of my databases. You can see this query joins 3 tables but in the end finds what it needs very quickly even though the tables are fairly large. Each sub-part only needs to reference one row:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sa    | NULL       | ref    | choice_id,user_id   | user_id | 5       | const                         |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | qc    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,question_id | PRIMARY | 4       | sa.choice_id                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | q     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY | 4       | qc.question_id                |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First, change

```
    where  ((ifnull(c.active,0) = 1)
              and  isnull(b.Result)
              and  isnull(b.ResultID))
```

to

```
    WHERE c.active = 1
      AND b.Result IS NULL
      AND b.ResultID IS NULL
```

I doubt if the Optimizer handles `IFNULL()` well.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`

You will probably now see that `c` is the first table in `EXPLAIN`.  Let's help the Optimizer by providing

```
c:  INDEX(active, col1)  -- in that order
```

After that,

```
a:  INDEX(col1)
d:  INDEX(Id)  -- unless it is already PRIMARY KEY(Id)
b:  INDEX(IsMatched, table2Id, SelectionId)  -- in any order
```

When dealing with `JOIN`, you need to figure out what order the tables will be looked at.  Do not trust `EXPLAIN` because it (initially) does not know what indexes you are about to add.

In your case, the `WHERE` referenced `c` and `b`.  But `b` is a `LEFT JOIN`, so we can't use it.  That leaves `c`.  The only useful column to index is `active` (after reformulating).  But that sounds like a simple, low-cardinality, "flag" that the Optimizer will shun.  I added something to the index in hopes that the optimizer will be tricked into using it.

So, what will the "next" table be?  The `JOINs` get from `c` only to `a`.  So `a` is next.  And the `JOIN` uses `col1`.

Next could be either `d` or `b`.  Looks like the `Optimizer could do them in either order, and will Optimize things the same regardless of the order.

`d`:  `Id` is how to get to it.

`b` needs 3 things in the `ON` to be checked with a simple `AND`.  So a "composite" index of those 3 columns, in any order.  (No, 'cardinality' of each column does not matter, even for picking the order.)

As for the `b... IS NULL` tests in the `WHERE` clause -- Those are presumably testing whether `LEFT` did not find a row.  (Usually only the PK is checked, so I don't know whether you are also checking something else.)

One more optimization...  Sometimes it is useful to build a "covering" index.  That is an `INDEX` that contains *all* the columns (for a table) mentioned *anywhere* in the `SELECT`.  This does not seem practical here, since it would involve lots of columns in each of the 4 cases.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to start with indexable columns in the `where` clause.  You don't have any (because of the function calls).  So, then start with the `join` columns:

```
from tblselection a join
     table1 c
     on c.col1 = a.col1 join
     table2 d
     on d.Id = a.table2Id left join
     tabletest 
     on b.SelectionId = a.selectionId and a.table2Id = b.table2Id and b.IsMatched = 1
```

I would start with `table1(col1)`, `table2(id)`, and `tabletest(SelectionId, table2Id, IsMatched)`.

Comment: Is tblselection(selectionId , table2Id ) not a good candidate for indexing?